# How can I allow more than 1 agent to build?

Tags: teamcity

On Agent Requirements, I've set:

```
system.agent.name EQUALS agent1
```

Now, the build only runs on agent1.

How can I make the build able to run either "agent1" and "agent2"?

So for example, if "agent1" is busy, then "agent2" is allowed to run instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of using EQUALS, you could use MATCHES and specify a regular expression.

Example: `system.agent.name MATCHES agent(1|2)`

[image: Screenshot showing agent requirement setting]

Comment: That's strange. I just tested on a TC 9.1.5 installation I have, and it works just fine. You also added an answer below indicating it worked when you set the value to (agent1|agent2)?

Comment: did you write right on this part? "agent(1|2)". Didn't you mean "(agent1|agent2)" ?

Comment: Yes, I had just the numbers inside the parenthesis. It's a regular expression that would match 1 OR 2. Have a look at the screenshot I just posted in my original answer. Here you can see my actual settings. My agent is called hrmts-build01 and it matches the expression hrmts-build(01|02). In this case I have only 1 agent, but that doesn't matter. If I add a second one with the name hrmts-build02 it will also match :) But in your case, using (agent1|agent2) would also work just fine. It's just a bit more specific.

Answer (score 7):

With the help of @henningst, I discovered this:

Parameter Name:

```
system.agent.name
```

Condition:

```
matches
```

Value:

```
(agent1|agent2)
```